# Lookup Projection Name from EPSG with ArcPy

Tags: arcpy, coordinate-system, arcmap, epsg, arcgis-10.7

Using ArcPy, how can I return the name of the projection based on an EPSG code, not a shapefile?

There are many questions/answers out there for doing something similar from a specific shapefile using .Describe(shp), but I haven't been able to get describe to work with an EPSG code.

For example, this:

```
info = arcpy.SpatialReference(4326).exportToString()
print info
```

Returns this: `GEOGCS['GCS_WGS_1984',DATUM['D_WGS_1984',SPHEROID['WGS_1984', ...`

But I just want it to return `'GCS_WGS_1984'`

Using `arcpy.SpatialReference(4326)`, returns a class, but I don't know how to unpack/access the info. `print(info.__dict__)` returns `{'_arc_object': <geoprocessing spatial reference object object at 0x02F2B1D0>}`. Since it's an object, I tried `print arcpy.Describe(info)` but that returned an I/O error.

I have read through the [SpatialReference Class Documentation](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/arcpy/classes/spatialreference.htm) but it is still not clear to me how to extract this info (which I think is "projectionName") from an EPSG code rather than a shapefile.

Comment: `print(arcpy.SpatialReference(4326).name)`

Comment: that worked. I actually tried .Name but didn't think to do it as lowercase. Thank you, I'll accept your answer if you post it below

Comment: Python class properties are always case-dependent.